# FastAPI - Documenting oneOf per Type?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, openapi, pydantic

The goal here is to provide different descriptions and labels in the auto-generated FastAPI docs, by possible input type. A simple example (route definition and Pydantic model) is as follows:

```
class DictOrString(BaseModel):
    arg: Dict | str = Field(None, title="Dict or String?")


@app.post("/mixed", description="Try mixing models anyOf")
async def mixed(inputs: DictOrString = Body()):
    return {"arg": inputs.arg, "type": f"{type(inputs.arg)=}"}
```

While functionally this works fine (dict sent in JSON format is interpreted as a Python dict, string input also works, tested with [httpie](https://httpie.io/)), the documentation for FastAPI or e.g., [this discussion](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4959) don't suggest a way to provide different descriptions for each type in this `anyOf` schema. Here are the screenshots from FastAPI's redoc section for the route above:

[image]

And selecting the second option (string):
[image]

Clearly, this would confuse a user ("Dict or String?" appears multiple times, as button labels, and in descriptions, repeating with or's). Is there a way to clearly title and describe the two different options (dict/object input vs. str) in the documentation?

The example here is relevant to dict & string, but the question can be generalized (e.g., UUID | str, or any other arbitrary type combinations).

**Edit I** - With `description` keyword in the field definition; still, this doesn't allow discriminating between anyOf types:

```
class DictOrString(BaseModel):
    arg: Dict | str = Field(None, title="Dict or String?", description="my desc")
```

[image]

Comment: If you replace `title="..."` with `description="..."`, does the doc look any better?

Comment: @Helen, this adds a nice description string to the , but not the ability to discriminate between types (namely, we're left with the same issue). Adding screenshot w/ description ketword.

Comment: I mean, if you remove `title` altogether but keep just `description="Dict or String"`. Does it look better? (`title` is used to override the schema name that's why it appears multiple times on your original screenshots.)

Comment: I tried both, it does improve the issue of title appearing everywhere, but I'm looking for a clear way to define _two_ titles, or descriptions for two different types, a single string  (as either title or description) can't address this issue.